# Creating a site collection doesn't seem to accept the template

Tags: powershell, site-collection, site-template

I'm creating a site collection and trying to apply a template to it

Here is the code:

```
$Siteurl = "http://myserver:8010/sites/sitex5"

New-SPSite $Siteurl  -OwnerAlias "mydomain\sp2k13admin" -Name "This will have a custom template" -Language 1040

Add-SPUserSolution -LiteralPath c:\temp\modelloit.wsp -Site $Siteurl


do

{
Write-Host "." -NoNewline -ForeGroundColor White;

    Start-Sleep -Seconds 5;

        try {
            $testsolution = Get-SPUserSolution -Identity modelloit.wsp -Site $Siteurl
            }
        catch{}

    } while(!$testsolution);

# it never gets to here as I see on the screen the dots to check for progression

Install-SPUserSolution -Identity modelloit.wsp -Site $Siteurl

Write-Host "Site collection with custom template is created"
```

The site gets created but when I open it, it seems that the template was not set as I get redirected to:

```
http://myserver:8010//sites/sitex5/_layouts/15/templatepick.aspx
```

[image]

So what am I missing to set a template properly after the creation
of a site collection?

**EDIT**
I have tried setting the template afterwards

```
$web = Get-SpWeb $Siteurl
```

$template = $web.GetAvailableWebTemplates(1033) | Where-Object {$_.Title -eq "modelloit"}

```
Write-host $template.Name #I see that it is correctly printend

Set-SPSite -Identity $Siteurl -Template $template.Name
```

but I get :

> WARNING: Template is not found and is not applied.

**EDIT2**
it works if instead of `Set-SPSite` I use

```
$web.ApplyWebTemplate($template.Name)
```

Comment: I think you are creating the site collection, then install the solution( i believe a template), But did you try to set the template via PowerShell after the install feature.I am not sure what's in code which is restraining it from applying.

Comment: I've tried setting afterwards as you can see in edit but no luck

Comment: #Waqas Sarwar MCSE see edit and edit2. If you want to put it as solution I'll flag it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to write PowerShell in 2 parts. One will create site collection and the other will apply custom template.

**Start Part 1**

Create a SharePoint Site Collection with a custom Template using Powershell

```
Write-Host “Provide the site collection URL e.g. http://intranet/site/custom”

$Siteurl = read-host

Write-Host “Provide the site collection owner email address”

$owner = read-host

New-SPSite $Siteurl -OwnerAlias $owner -Name “This will have a custom template”
```

**End Part 1** :- Create a SharePoint Site Collection with a custom Template using Powershell

Now we have to add our WSP to the Solution Gallery in the Site Collection. I have a do While loop to make sure that the solution has been uploaded successfully before activating it.

**Start Part 2**

Create a SharePoint Site Collection with a custom Template using PowerShell

```
Add-SPUserSolution -LiteralPath d:\temp.wsp -Site $Siteurl

$ErrorActionPreference = “silentlycontinue”

do

{

Write-Host “.” -NoNewline -ForeGroundColor White;

Start-Sleep -Seconds 5;

try

{

$testsolution = Get-SPUserSolution -Identity temp.wsp -Site $Siteurl

}

catch

{}

} while(!$testsolution);

$ErrorActionPreference = “stop”

Install-SPUserSolution -Identity temp.wsp -Site $Siteurl

Write-Host “Site collection with custom template is created”
```

Comment: Have you tried above solution?

Comment: But this is just what I wrote in my post.

Comment: You need to follow the step which I mentioned in my answer in serialized form...

Comment: Do you mean that I have to make two scripts and launch them separately?

Comment: Yes of course...

Comment: I can't confirm that it works yes as it's taking ages and I only see dots. Anyway, I wonder what the difference between one script and separating it in two chunks? Could you tell me why  two scripts instead of one should work?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/40991/discussion-between-hardik-and-gyonder).